# Can't read or write to the firebase realtime database (android studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I think I connect to the firebase because I received the message for the terminal which is

```
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

And I think I set the rules correct

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Here are my read and write codes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Read from the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            System.out.println(value);
            Log.d("T", "Value is: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("F", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
}
```

And a very weird thing, it can print the value, but the data is never get updated in the console.

printed value

```
I/System.out: Hello, World!
D/T: Value is: Hello, World!
```

but in the console...[image]

Comment: What do you mean the data never gets updated? You don't see anything in the console?

Comment: Yes, in the console...

Answer (score 2):

**You have to push the messages so they don't get updated each time:**

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

//use a map
Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();  
message.put("text", "Hello, World!");

myRef.push().setValue(message);
```

**After this your messages will look like this:**

```
message
|
|----------randomID
           |-----text : "Hello, World!"
|
|
```

**To read the messages text:**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Read from the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              //this loops through all random ids and grabs the text 
              //you can maybe store the text in some list and do whatever.
              String value = ds.child("text").getValue(String.class);
              System.out.println(value);
              Log.d("T", "Value is: " + value);

             }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("F", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it didn't work.....this time even I can't find the printed message, and nothing changed in the console.

Comment: Did you refresh the console page?

Comment: a key (message) and a value (none). As shown in the picture above

Comment: Did you do exactly what I told you? Did you call some other thing, other than what I told you? Did you delete your old code?

Comment: Yes, I just copied and pasted your code and didn't call other things, and I deleted all the old code.

Comment: I notice sth in the terminal which is "W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed without exception message. Will retry token retrieval" Is that ok?

Comment: I updated the writing code, check it and see what happens.

Comment: emm...still nothing change, Is that I actually didn't connect to the database at all?

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet?

Comment: I think so because I use my own android phone. And I also have google play service on my phone.

Comment: delete the node from the console make it blank, then run the app again.

Comment: are you on the main page of the console? I mean are you on the root node of the app in the cosole?

Comment: How to check whether I am on the main page or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
    tableUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         tv.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + dataSnapshot, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: DatabaseReference tableUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message");
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

//use a map
        Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put("text", "Hello, World;;!");
        tableUser.setValue(message);

Comment: from that code value is added succesfully and exact same

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely stupid, but if for anyone it is not working in an emulator then try it in a real device, i really don't know why but it worked for me.

Comment: This was my case. Helped me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I encounter this problem too. I connect to firebase via a tool on IntelliJ and I can Logcat firebaseProjectID which means it already connect to firebase. So I create a new project and copy all the code from the old project, connect to firebase via tool and it works normally with both read and write DB without touching any code. This is a very annoying solution but easier than trying to find a solution on the internet, which I still can't find them.